# Synapse column store datetime encoding

Tags: columnstore, encoding, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a table in an Azure Synapse database. This table has a clustered columnstore index. It has a datetime column. The minimum value in this column is 2001-03-27 00:00:00 and the maximum is 2022-12-31 00:00:00.

When I look at sys.pdw_nodes_column_store_segments ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-pdw-nodes-column-store-segments-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7)). This column has encoding_type "2 = VALUE_HASH_BASED - non-string/binary column with common values in dictionary" for all segments.

The smallest min_data_id and largest max_data_id are 158806415769600 and 192947110805504 respectively.

How do the values in the data_id columns relate to the source data in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE 
    @dt1 datetime = '2001-03-27 00:00:00',
    @dt2 datetime = '2022-12-31 00:00:00';

SELECT 
    dt1 = CONVERT(bigint, CONVERT(binary(8), @dt1)),
    dt2 = CONVERT(bigint, CONVERT(binary(8), @dt2));
```

| dt1 | dt2 |
| --- | --- |
| 158806415769601 | 192947110805504 |

The first four bytes are the number of days since '1900-01-01'.
The second four bytes are the number of 1/300s intervals since midnight.